# foreign characters (i.e. Chinese) from HTML using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a text file of 1,000+ URLs, with each URL linking to a journal entry of text. Some of these entries contain Chinese or Japanese characters.

I would like to save each entry using BeautifulSoup. However, I cannot figure out how encoding and decoding works in this situation. I've browsed Stack Overflow for help, and I can only find instances in which the string itself is known and set as a variable.

However, given that I am scraping from a list of URLs, I do not know what strings I will find until I collect them.

This is what I have so far:

```
with open(data_src) as f:
  resp = requests.get(f.readlines()[419])
  raw_text = resp.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text, 'html.parser')
  for s in soup.findAll('script'):
      s.replaceWith('')
  entry = soup.select('div#body_show_ori')[0]
  print(entry.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

This is the string that prints:

> b'\n\xe6\x88\x91\xe7\xbb\x88\xe4\xba\x8e\xe5\x88\xb0\xe4\xba\x86\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe5\x8e\xa6\xe9\x97\xa8\xe3\x80\x82\xe6\x88\x91\xe8\xa7\x89\xe5\xbe\x97\xe8\xbf\x99\xe9\x87\x8c\xe5\xbe\x88\xe7\x83\xad\xe5\xbe\x88\xe6\xbd\xae\xe6\xb9\xbf\xe3\x80\x82\xe7\x8e\xb0\xe5\x9c\xa8\xe6\x88\x91\xe6\xb2\xa1\xe6\x9c\x89\xe6\x9c\x8b\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\x80\x8c\xe4\xb8\x94\xe8\xbf\x99\xe4\xb8\xaa\xe5\x9c\xb0\xe6\x96\xb9\xe6\x88\x91\xe4\xb8\x8d\xe7\x86\x9f\xe6\x82\x89\xe3\x80\x82\xe4\xb8\x8d\xe6\x95\xa2\xe5\x87\xba\xe5\x8e\xbb\xe5\xa4\x96\xe9\x9d\xa2\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x80\x82\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe6\x97\xa0\xe8\x81\x8a\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x80\x82\xe3\x80\x82\n'

This is where I'm stuck; I'm trying to figure out how to decode the string from here.

Comment: Try remove `.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @KevinGuan I get ''ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-54: ordinal not in range(128)', hence why I am trying to encode (and inevitably decode, though I'm not sure how to go about doing that)

Comment: Hmm...and then decode it? Try `.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I am not sure but check out `unicode_escape` too

Comment: @KevinGuan I get the same error message. From what I understand, I have to decode it using something separate, and I'm unsure what this would be.

Comment: @SydneyMaples: Well, are you using Windows and Python 3?

Comment: @KevinGuan I am using Python 3.5 and OS X

Comment: @SydneyMaples: That's fine, try `.decode('gb18030', 'ignore')`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Same error message, unfortunately.

Comment: @SydneyMaples: Hmm...what's the link?

Comment: @KevinGuan The link I'm testing on is http://lang-8.com/1699/journals/224697/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96089/discussion-between-kevin-guan-and-sydney-maples).

Comment: Your problem is *“how to print an Unicode string”*. It has nothing to do with beautifulsoup.

Comment: *“I can only find instances in which the string itself is known and set as a variable”* → those are just examples. That's how you recude a program to an [MSVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will not work differently if that unicode string happens to come from a library.

Answer (score -1):

Try decoding *before* passing the data to beautifulsoup.

IIRC coreectly, if you pass a unicode object, it will not decode it again.